# using queue to get some characters from input string. return value is weird

Tags: c#, queue

i can't find any mistakes in my code.
here i'm trying to pick all numbers from the string:
(just to simplify the example,, i want to pick numbers that will satisfy some condition)
i use Queue cause i don't want to deal with array's indexes.

```
        Console.Write("enter string: ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] array = s.ToCharArray();
        Queue<char> q = new Queue<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            q.Enqueue(array[i]);
        }

        char[] new_array = new char[q.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
        {
            new_array[i] = q.Dequeue();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new String(new_array));
```

Input string: 123456
And the output is a little weird:
123

another input: 123
output: 12

of course i made some mistake) but everything seems to be OK
Thank YOU in advance

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < new_array.Length; i++)`

Comment: Can you explain what some condition is?

Comment: any condition, i meant in the future.... now the condition is all numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the second loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
    {
        new_array[i] = q.Dequeue();
    }
```

As `q.Count` decrements on every loop iteration, and `i` increases on every interation, you get only half of the elements.

try something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; q.Count > 0; i++)
    {
        new_array[i] = q.Dequeue();
    }
```

also consider: [Queue.toArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.toarray%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `List<char>` instead of `Queue<char>` and `char[]`.  There's nothing here that particularly needs a queue, and it would avoid the problem that Rudolf pointed out, and a `List` is much easier to work with than an array. You can also use `foreach` instead of a `for` loop, and avoid the intermediate step.

```
    Console.Write("enter string: ");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    List<char> new_array = new List<char>();
    foreach(char c in s.ToCharArray())
    {
        new_array.Add(c);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(new String(new_array.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

As the reason for your error is already stated,you can replace your two loops with just two statements

```
//A version of Queue constructor accepts IEnumerable object.
//you can directly pass the string to the queue constructor.
Queue<char> Que = new Queue<char>("123456");

//Copies the array and the position is preserved
var new_arr= Que.ToArray();
```

Comment: He'd need to use `.Where()` to get his not-yet-specified logic into there, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

> Removes and returns the object at the beginning of the Queue.

Answer (score 0):

As you use Dequeue(), the q.Count value changes in each iteration.
So rather than using q.Count in this loop;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
```

use

```
 int queueSize = q.Count;
 for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++)
```

This will keep your looping limit as a constant number rather than calculating it in each iteration to find a different value because of using Dequeue().